# Memory leak symfony and monolog and console

Tags: php, symfony, memory-leaks, doctrine-orm, monolog

I spent the last 2 hours trying to find my memory leak.

- Optimized the doctrine bulk processing
- Optimized my detach and all that doctrine annotation stuff
- Optimized the SQL Logger
- The script was still leaking
- Decided to comment out the logging because there wasn't much I could do anyway

Turns out that

- Over 40k iterations without logging at each n but at modulus 50, start mem: 28 mb end mem: 30mb
- Over 5k iterations with logging at each n, no modulus, start mem:28mb, end mem 38mb.

Example

```
 # this leaks
 # start mem: 28 mb end mem: 38mb, n = 5k
 foreach ($this->queryData->iterate() as $j => $data):
            declare(ticks = 1);
            self::$currentAd++;
            $this->em->detach($data[0]);
            $this->logger->info(LogUtility::getMemoryUsage() . " (" . self::$currentAd .")");
            if(self::$currentAd === 40000 ):
                break(2);
            endif;
  endforeach;

 # this doesn't leak
 # start mem: 28 mb end mem: 30mb, n = 40k
 foreach ($this->queryData->iterate() as $j => $data):
            declare(ticks = 1);
            self::$currentAd++;
            $this->em->detach($data[0]);
            if(self::$currentAd % 50 == 0):
                  $this->logger->info(LogUtility::getMemoryUsage() . " (" . self::$currentAd .")");
            endif;
            if(self::$currentAd === 40000 ):
                break(2);
            endif;
  endforeach;
```

my monolog config:

```
 handlers:
    test:
        type:   stream
        path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/immobilier/test.log"
        level:  debug
        channels: test
  console:
        type:   console
        bubble: false
        verbosity_levels:
            VERBOSITY_VERBOSE: INFO
            VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE: DEBUG
        channels: [test]
```

Any suggestions to correct this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution. I can't tell you the exact reasons why such memory leak happen, however according to [this](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/118); Adding the `--no-debug` option to your command solves the problem. It actually did and it even reduced the memory by 2mb. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @delmalki's answer, you might want to check if you have any `fingers_crossed` handler and set the `buffer_size`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler: grouped
            excluded_404s:
                - ^
            buffer_size: 30
```